# What tools do you recommend to build a UI for a Powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell, user-interface

What is the best tool to create a GUI from scratch for a PowerShell script. The script may contain multiple functions and so require multiple buttons linked to each function. There also needs to be a output area to display results of operations.

Answer (score 5):

[PowerShell Studio 2012](http://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) from Sapien has a built-in GUI designer, but it's fairly expensive.

There's also the [ShowUI module](http://showui.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex, which is free, as is the WPK - which is part of the [PowerShellPack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack).

All of these tools are great, and PowerShell is an awesome language, but if you really need to have a graphical user interface for your script, you should perhaps question whether you're actually writing a program instead.  If you're actually writing a program, using a language like C# may be a better decision.

If you want an example of a script with a UI, you can check out [Convert-WindowsImage](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-WindowsImageps1-0fe23a8f), which I wrote a year or so ago.  It would have been much easier to write Convert-WindowsImage as a C# program, but I decided that it was more interesting to showcase what PowerShell can do.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I steel use two solutions (well hidden on the web but still existing) to solve your problem :

**First**, You can use [Sapiens PrimalForms Community Edition](http://www.sapien.com/downloads#Community%20Tools/32%20Bit/PrimalFormsCE.exe) (It's free, you just have to sign to Sapiens and go to download).This Framwork allow you to graphicaly build your DialogBox and then it generates the PowerShell Code for Windows Forms (still avalaible as shown here under).

[image]

**Second** you've got a script called [PowerShell Form Converter](http://powershell-scripting.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=134&Itemid=71) writen by Arnaud Petitjean (11-05-2007). Once again you have to register, the article is writen in french, but you can download a Powershell script that transform a Windows Form from a .CS file to a PS1. Like in Sapiens editor, the transformation is commented (here in french) with the place to code events.

Answer (score 2):

You have full access to .NET libraries with PowerShell. I've used Visual Studio before to cobble together a dialog using Winforms and then copied and pasted the code it generated into my powershell script.

something like...

```
function createGUI{
     [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
     ...
     $main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
     $button_OK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
     ....
     $main_form.ShowDialog()
}

createGUI
```

Comment: Why use reflection here?  Sorry if the question makes no sense, I just don't understand the second line of code where you call `System.Reflection.Assembly`